# Dividing two sets of points using a polynomial

Tags: python, data-science

I have to set of points. My job is to fit a polynomial line to divide them in the best way (probably using MSE of each point), e.g. [image]

Where points are my data and I want to get this red line. I tried numpy.polyfit, but this doesn't seem to work. Is there any function that can achieve that?

Comment: Please show what you have already tried as well as your data.

Comment: I suggest you try SVM with a polynomial kernel of 2 degrees.

Comment: @RockyLi Okay, I misinterpreted problem. SVM are the way to go. Thanks